# How to calculate stacked event duration in pandas

Tags: python, excel, pandas, algorithm, dataframe

I have  events with stacked start and end time. The goal is to calculate the total duration of each event. Pivot for pandas produce wrong results due to overlapping of tasks timings in each event

[image]

for example, the duration for events should be

```
event 1 10:16:08 
event 2 9:07:48 
event 3 6:08:46
```

When I use pivot with pandas I get wrong results apparently due to the stack nature of the event tasks

```
pd.pivot_table(df, values = 'Duration', index=['event'],aggfunc=np.sum).reset_index().sort_values('Duration').tail(10)
```

please point me in the right direction of how to solve this problem. I can solve this by looping through start and end date for each event, but this would be lengthy and unnecessary

So, as a simple example: 2 tasks in event 1  (8 am to 10 am, and 9 am to 11 am) should give a result of 3 hours instead of 4 hours by simple duration summation

Comment: What is the output you are expecting?

Comment: I want to calculate the total inclusive duration of an event, so for example: if event 1 has tasks from 8 to 10 am, and another from 9 am to 11 am-> then I want event1 total duration to be 3 hours from 8 am to 11 am . What I am getting is sum of all durations , which isn't useful for me

Comment: [Please don't upload images of data or code on SO](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: you just want the difference of the min and max for each event. I would do it for you but I don't feel like retyping your data

Comment: I will repost the data shortly, but this wouldn't always work since I may have times like below: 
8 to 10 am, 9 to 11 am, and 1 to 5 pm